# Are Multimedia keyboards able to control Xbox Music on Windows 8?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8, xbox-music

Pausing and playing music inside the Xbox Music app on Windows 8 takes a minimum of three clicks from the desktop.  If I were to purchase a Multimedia keyboard with pause, play, fast forward, and rewind buttons, would they work while being at the Desktop?

If I don't own a multimedia keyboard, would I be able to use something like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### It works for me.

I can speak from my experience. I have a Dell keyboard that looks like this:

[image: Dell keyboard]

Above the <kbd>Insert</kbd> and <kbd>Home</kbd> keys there is a block of multimedia control keys: Play/Pause, Stop, Skip Back, Skip Forward.

If I have music playing in the Music app, these keys work as expected. When I use them I get visual feedback, too. In the top-left corner of the screen, where the volume display normally shows, information about what is playing is added whenever I press those multimedia keys on the keyboard.

[image: On-screen display]

### No multimedia keyboard?

Take a look at [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/279000/15210) to see how to use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to remap available key combinations to send the multimedia key codes your keyboard cannot produce natively.

Comment: I upvoted this just for Muse. (Nice screenshots and good answer, though.)

Comment: Using another Dell keyboard with media keys, I can confirm this works. For integrated media keys in laptops, it depends on the laptot, drivers, etc..