# Keyboard shortcut for playing song in Xbox Music inWindows 8?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, xbox-music

When I listen Xbox Music and I change the volume using the volume keys on my laptop, a nice "now playing" overlay appears on the screen, with play/skip controls.

On my desktop keyboard I don't have volume keys, there is a keyboard shortcut to show the "now playing"/volume overlay?

It looks like it's system-wide, so there should be a keyboard shortcut, I think

Comment: Not sure about the shortcut, but if you want you can try remapping unused keys (F11, F12?) to volume up/down using a program like SharpKeys.

Comment: I'm also interested on this, I'm sure multimedia keyboards can use the  next and previous song buttons correctly. However this might interest you : http://superuser.com/questions/497805/are-multimedia-keyboards-able-to-control-xbox-music-on-windows-8