# Is it possible to change my computer's volume with my mouse?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, shortcuts

I had a Logitech MX1100 mouse that I was using to change my computer's volume -- I mapped the DPI rocker switch to volume change (repeating). But that mouse has now been replaced with a Performance MX mouse, which unfortunately, doesn't have that rocker switch anymore.

I've been thinking about other ways I could map volume change to the mouse. I thought about the possibility of holding a modifier switch (like shift) while using the scrollwheel to change it, but can't find possible settings to do so.

I've also wondered about the possibility of holding a modifier switch, holding right click (for example), and then moving the mouse either up or down to increase/decrease the volume.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I'm also looking for a method that can be universally across the system. For instance, on my old mouse, I could use the DPI rocker switch to adjust volume anywhere, even in the middle of a game. I'm wondering if some type of "fundamental"/universal action, such as a right click from a mouse, is going to be hooked/captured by the forefront program, thereby pulling the carpet out from underneath the volume change function (modification).

Comment: google: "autohotkey global key scroll volume" >  http://superuser.com/questions/278951/my-keyboard-has-no-media-keys-can-i-control-media-without-them -- not exactly what you're looking for, but you could write your own script.

Comment: The universal part is the tricky thing here. If the keys are detected as 'regular' keys, AHK would work. The configuration software for the mouse itself would be a good, non universal starting point to sort this out, IMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option I found and settled on is with a free program called "Volumouse" by Nirsoft. Very customizable, very lightweight, very free.

Besides it's universal-access, the best part about it is its vast ability for customization, being able to use any and all possible mouse/keyboard shortcuts, even setting multiple shortcuts concurrently (e.g., multiple keyboard shortcuts + a mouse shortcut, etc.).

Works fantastically.

[Volumouse](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/volumouse.html)

Answer (score 1):

Check out AutoHotKey. The link below has a script example you could use which will remap your mouse wheel to control the volume when the mouse is hovering over the taskbar.

[AutoHotKey Controlling Volume](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/7977-volumouse-trick-mouse-volume-control-over-taskbar-only/#entry49762)

I'm sure this script could also be modified so that if you hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and scroll, it'll control your volume.