# Use mouse buttons on screen corners to perform certain actions in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mouse, mouse-wheel, hot-corner

I want to use mouse buttons on screen corners to perform certain actions.

Specifically, I want to use the mouse wheel:
-on the bottom left corner to raise and lower the sound volume;
-and on the top right corner to make page up and page down.

In Linux, such tasks can be easily done, for example using a script like [this](https://github.com/mnural/xlib-pyvolume) or using Compiz.

How can I do this on Windows 10?

edit: I can't code or build scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You could program something like this easily. I recommend using C#. Setup a project with a low-level Mouse Hook and start Coding. If you can't program, ask a friend who can ;)

Comment: Or Visual Basic

Comment: I can't code and neither any of my acquaintances  can, if so perhaps I wouldn't have needed to create this thread in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

The term for this is "Hot Corners", where actions are attributed to corners,
and you need a third-party product for that since Windows does not support it.

The article
[6 Free Tools to Enable and Customize Hot Corners in Windows](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/have-mac-os-x-hot-corners-feature-in-windows/)
lists these products:

- [Hot Corners 2](https://sites.google.com/site/programsforpeers/hotcorners)
- [HotCornersApp](https://sites.google.com/site/bytecar/home/hotcornersapp/hotcornersapprelease15)
- [Preme](http://www.premeforwindows.com/)
- [Hot Corners WX](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/Hot-Corners-WX.shtml)
- [WinXCorners](https://apps.codigobit.info/2015/10/winxcorners-hot-corners-for-windows-10.html)
- [BetterDesktopTool](http://www.betterdesktoptool.com/download.html)

See the linked article for details about installing and using each of
the products, and try them out.

For controlling the sound you may use
[NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)
(see [examples](https://superuser.com/a/42042/8672)).

For sending Page-Up/Down you may use
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
with two one-liner scripts, each script containing one of the two
commands below:

```
Send {PgUp}

Send {PgDn}
```

Comment: I tried them all but unfortunately none of them does what I need.

Comment: Most allow running a program or script, which can be used for doing anything, including sound levels and sending keyboard keys.

Comment: Unfortunately I not have the necessary knowledge to do such a thing. Is there a way to modify the script I mentioned in my initial post so it runs on Windows?

Comment: I added information about that part.

Comment: What is missing is the part of those commands only being executed if I use the mouse wheel on the corner, for what I understand I could assign those commands to a corner but they would be executed every time that the mouse pointer is on the corner and not only when I move the mouse wheel up or down on the corner.

Comment: If none of the products suits you, you would need to write your own.