# How to create or is there a shortcut to mute the sound of the current window/program?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, shortcuts

What I want to do is mute the sound of the current program/window in Windows.

How I would normally go about this, is RMB on Sound Icon in taskbar (or through Control Panel -> Sound) -> Open Volume Mixer -> Find the program I want and hit the sound icon to mute it.
I'm looking for a shortcut, either a system one, or a hack, or an Autohotkey script or some 3d party program that does that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Windows sound volume via the command line](https://superuser.com/questions/42039/change-windows-sound-volume-via-the-command-line)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik It appears all of those options change the system sound. How to change the sound of an individual program though (as happens in Volume Mixer).