# How can i change my microphone gain via commandline or prompt?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, microphone, prompt

is it possible to change microphone gain via prompt/command line ? I already tried everything to change it, downloaded equalizer apo, updated drivers... i think the only way it's prompt/command line.

Comment: Nircmd works in W10>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/42039/change-windows-sound-volume-via-the-command-line