# NirCmd volume control of certain applications from Volume Mixer not working?

Tags: batch-file, autohotkey, nircmd

So I use this app to mute microphone communication in Valorant.
But I also want to mute the game itself.

The devs of the game have separated these 2 so in Volume Mixer (`SndVol.exe`) they are 2 processes one called:

`RiotClientServices.exe`  the microphone comms which I can mute just fine with this command in a batch file:

```
nircmd.exe muteappvolume RiotClientServices.exe 2
```

And the second one which is the main game volume which I never got it to work and I don't know what the issue is:
`nircmd.exe muteappvolume VALORANT-Win64-Shipping.exe 2`

I know the app works fine cause for `chrome.exe` and the previous `.exe` I mentioned it works but for `VALORANT-Win64-Shipping.exe` it doesn't do anything. I suspect maybe there's something with the dash symbol or the numbers in the file name (I can't test this theory cause I can't change the filename of the game cause it will not open anymore) or maybe it is the wrong file name but that's not possible.

Nirsoft actually has another software with a GUI called soundvolumeview which can make this easy it creates a shortcut of the program and it has every program listed but that has compatibility issues with my system or windows 10 so the app constantly is frozen , I managed to find a version which didn't freeze version 2.06 but that is freezing too these days hence I am asking the question here.

I really would love if NirCmd worked cause that just works instantly meanwhile soundvolumeview has real performance issues and even when it works there's a delay.

I have trying adding quotes like

```
nircmd.exe muteappvolume "VALORANT-Win64-Shipping.exe" 2
```

tried
Process Path ID:

```
nircmd.exe muteappvolume "C:\Riot Games\VALORANT\live\ShooterGame\Binaries\Win64\VALORANT-Win64Shipping.exe" 2
```

doesn't work either even thou this works for other apps like chrome or RiotClientServices

I feel like I have tried everything possible.

Edit:

@DavidPostill
Yes I have sent them an email a year ago but they didn't reply.

@harrymc
Yes of course it shows its the main volume of the game , and as I explained it can kind of work with the other app SoundVolumeView

Edit2:
SoundVolumeView has now new command line type app which also faces the problem of being buggy and freezes but that might be related to me muting most devices and removing microphone and maybe the app is looking for a long time to find those devices and that maybe causes the freezing.

Edit3:
It turns out that if I disable my useless monitor Playback device option in sounds it causes me issues in soundvolumeview 2.06 version where it takes a good 15 seconds to take a command.
Even more weird there are 2 monitor playback options one which is the 3.5mm jack output which works fine and even if disabled doesn't affect the program, but the other one with the exact same name in the playback devices there which says is unplugged.

The newer versions of SoundVolumeView have that issue of freezing more pronounced so they are un-usable at all.

Solution:
Not optimal but the only one is don't mess with the monitor playback devices in sounds options. Don't disable them especially those that say disconnected and are related to your monitor. I don't know what they do but apparently they do something important for SoundVolumeView

Comment: Have you [contacted](https://www.nirsoft.net/contact-new.html) Nirsoft?

Comment: While the game is working, if you right-click on the Sound traybar icon and select "Open Volume mixer", do you see and can control the sound volume of the game? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc I put the answer on the end as an edit or should I have done it here? 
Sorry if I did it wrong new around here.

Comment: The syntax of `@user` only works in a comment, not in your post. Adding information to your post is good, but specific answers are better put in comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Windows sound volume via the command line](https://superuser.com/questions/42039/change-windows-sound-volume-via-the-command-line)

Comment: @harrymc
 No that question is about Windows main volume or recording devices ,  my question is specific  about software volume also the app suggested there is already talked in length here and the reason why that doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn' t have to do with the file name because I tested using VLC, if I changed the vlc exe name to the one I have an issue with it it didn't have a problem recognizing it was vlc even with the new file name VALORANT-Win64-Shipping.exe

Comment: Please improve the title (NirCmd volume control...) and add the solution as an answer, This way it can become properly visible and potentially upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Nircmd has not been updated for a long time and there is no solution for it since the software source code is probably proprietary.

But the application they maintain from NirSoft SoundVolumeView works and has a GUI.
Newer versions seem to freeze and bug out and stall on my PC but version 2.06 can be kind of reliable if you know it's bugs and kinks.
You can use that version to create a mute shortcut or specific volume control percentages for individual applications that are running in windows.

Make sure not to disable any monitor audio output
even if the monitors themselves don't have any audio hardware.

```
Sounds>Playback> Playback devices
```

In my specific case they were named:

```
MONITOR BRAND NAME XYZ
Nvidia High definition Audio
```

If you disable the above SoundVolumeView will freeze for 15 seconds for some reason.

I am running Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC so keep that in mind if someone else is running some other version of windows.

**Alternate solution** is to get rid of all the headache is to uninstall completely all Nvidia High definition Audio drivers from device manager

```
Device Manager>Sound, video and game controllers> NVIDIA XYZ
```

*Right click and uninstall device*

Disabling will add problems for version 2.06 , but uninstalling makes the sound volume view app work fine even in the newer versions so this is the most optimal solution of all if you don't use/need Nvidia audio drivers.

**Sound volume view** gets confused by those virtual audio devices so its better to remove them completely, and **nircmd** is old don't use it, if you need something in command line like **nircmd** *use **SoundVolumeCommandLine** a 2021 iteration of the GUI appliaction but this time without GUI.*

note:
I have noticed even some voice modulation software that create virtual audio devices have weird interactions with other software that leads to weird bugs.

Comment: The alternate solution of uninstalling works only temporarily  because if you plug your mic in and out for some reason it restarts the nvidia drivers that I previously uninstalled. So the only option is to nuke NVIDIA completely with DDU

Comment: Ok those drivers keep getting installed by themselves where i remove and put mic back on or when I restart even if you don't install Nvidia Audio drivers they are there and are called "Digital Audio (HDMI) High Definition Audio Device"